# Re-generate the exact underlying data from an exact MRF model or any other PGMs

Tags: probability, inference, graphical-model, graph-theory, markov-random-field

I was wondering if there exist a way to re-generate the actual underlying data (not a sample!) from a given exactly learned MRF. In other words, lets say I have a discrete factorised joint distribution P(X) which has been learned on a dataset D exactly, how can I re-generate D from P(X).

The model could be any Probabilistic Graphical Model (PGMs).

Is there any algorithm for that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you can’t in general.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks for the answer. Any reason for the claim?

Comment: Exponential family distributions have finite number of sufficient statistics regardless of the data size. You can keep pumping data into the model, but everything is blurred into those statistics.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy please note the model is an exact discrete MRF, nothing is blurred there. thanks anyway!